# В комментариях неразрывные пробелы заменяются обычными

Tags: дефект, статус-так-задумано, комментарии

Если запостить комментарий с неразрывными пробелами, они превращаются в обычные.
А раньше ведь работало.

PS: Сначала совсем про другое думал (если интересно, см. [первую версию вопроса](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/revisions/2943/1)).

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky, почему?

Comment: Я вижу [неразрывный пробел в комментарии (в `s='1 2'; unicodedata.name(s[1])=='NO-BREAK SPACE'`)](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/571831/python-%d0%b4%d0%bb%d0%b8%d0%bd%d0%b0-%d1%81%d1%82%d1%80%d0%be%d0%ba%d0%b8-%d0%b1%d0%b5%d0%b7-%d1%83%d1%87%d0%b5%d1%82%d0%b0-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b1%d0%b5%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%b2/571863#comment752452_571863)

Comment: @jfs, возможно, дело в том, что он в коде? Попробуем-ка применить. `Попробуем-ка применить.` - в куске кода копипаст фразы раньше. Пробел должен быть неразрывным.

Comment: @jfs, да, из двух неразрывных пробелов уцелел лишь тот, что в коде.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Неразрывные пробелы — это не только и не столько обход ограничения на минимальную длину комментария, сколько возможность нормально отформатировать текст. **Типографика** предписывает не разрывать сокращения (например, *"и т. д."*), не отделять число от единиц измерения (например, *"10 км"*), не переносить тире посередине предложения на новую строку и т. п. В рамках цифрового текста это означает повсеместное использование неразрывных пробелов.

Если неразрывные пробелы превращать в обычные, то вся красота типографики рушится. Я возмущён до глубины души таким наплевательским отношением к оформлению текста.

Это могло бы иметь какие-то оправдания на заре Интернета, когда длинные строки могли ломать вёрстку, но в современном мире, где все браузеры умеют насильно переносить строки, подобное надругательство над текстом нельзя воспринимать иначе как вандализм, особенно на сайтах, где основное наполнение — текст.

P. S. В этом сообщении 15 неразрывных пробелов.

Comment: Вроде всего 12?

Comment: _"обход ограничения на минимальную длину комментария"_ - они в этой роли никогда не работали. Работали пробелы нулевой ширины, а неразрывные, как и обычные, просто не учитывались при подсчёте 15 символов.